# Plotting a subset of the index of a list

Tags: python, plot, plotly, visualization

My aim is to make a scatter plot were the first half of the data has a different colour as the second half of the data. I tried to plot both parts of the index separately, but could not get it to look like I want to. The plot is part of a subplot, hence the "subplot" in the code below.

So in short, can I select part of the index from L[i] and then proceed to make two plots in the same figure? Or is there a direct way to change colour of the first half of the index.

```
fig2 = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, subplot_titles=("Rainfall-Runoff graph", "Runoff Ratio"))

fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=L[i].index, y=L[i]['RR'], mode='markers', name= 'C'), row=2, col=1)

fig2.update_yaxes(title_text='I', row=2, col=1)
```

The plot is part of a loop, hence the [i] of the lists.

Comment: Question unclear. Which one do you want? 1. make a scatter plot were the first half of the data has a different colour as the second half of the data, or 2. select part of the index from L[i] and then proceed to make two plots in the same figure? 1 or 2? To the question "Or is there a direct way to change colour of the first half of the index?" The answer is "yes, you can change the color of the first half of the index"

Comment: Doesnt that do the same thing? My solution for two colours was to first plot the first half of the index and then plot the second half of the index. But I am very interested in how to change the color of the first half of the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use **numpy** slicing
- below shows first half of data in blue and second have in red

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
val = np.random.uniform(1,5,100)
go.Figure([go.Scatter(y=val[0:51]),
           go.Scatter(y=np.concatenate([np.full(50, np.nan), val[50:100]]))])
```